# Ifand statements using hours/minutes in Excel

Tags: excel

Need a formula for the following 4 situations

- If you work less than 9 hours and your break is less than 30:59
  minutes, I want a `0`.
- If you work less than 9 hours and your break is
  more than 31 minutes, I want a `1`
- If you work more than 9 hours and
  your break is less than 45:59 minutes, I want a `0`
- If you work more
  than 9 hours and your break is more than 46 minutes, I want a `1`

Here is what I have so far.  Most of it works but not all the statements.

For example:

- C2 = staffed time listed as 9:55:21
- G2 = break time listed as :40:46

  ```
  =IF(AND(C2<"9:00:00",G2<":30:59"),0,
     IF(AND(C2>"9:00:01",G2<":45:59"),0,
        IF(AND(C2<"9:00:00",G2>":31:00"),1,
          IF(AND(C2>"9:00:01",G2>":46:00"),1,"FALSE"))))
  ```

I can get some of the situations to work but I can't get all 4 of them to work.  I'm thinking it may be a formatting issue with the time

Comment: You probably want `=IF(C2<TIME(9,0,0),IF(G2<TIME(0,31,0),0,1),IF(G2<TIME(0,46,0),0,1))`, but you need to make sure that the two fields are entered as valid time values.

Answer (score 1):

OP commented that both staffed-time and and break-time can be ill-formatted. So first we'd better format these data into proper `date`-type. When `string`-typed `U2` is `9:55:21` or `:51:13` or `51:13`, below formulae will format it properly.

- `V2`: `=FIND(":", U2)`
- `W2`: `=IFERROR(FIND(":", U2, V2+1), 0)`
- `X2`: `=IF(W2=0, TIME(0,LEFT(U2,V2-1),MID(U2,V2+1,2)),
  IF(V2>1,TIME(LEFT(U2,V2-1),MID(U2,V2+1,2),MID(U2,W2+1,2)),TIME(0,MID(U2,V2+1,2),MID(U2,W2+1,2))))`

So if you get the proper `date`-typed for both staffed-time(`X2`) and break-time(say `AC2`), then you can get `0` or `1` based on your four conditions in order. (this formula can be shortened, but I didn't do for clarity.)

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(X2)<9,  HOUR(AC2)*60 + MINUTE(AC2)<31), 0,
 IF(AND(HOUR(X2)<9,  HOUR(AC2)*60 + MINUTE(AC2)>=31), 1,
 IF(AND(HOUR(X2)>=9, HOUR(AC2)*60 + MINUTE(AC2)<46), 0,
 IF(AND(HOUR(X2)>=9, HOUR(AC2)*60 + MINUTE(AC2)>=46), 1))))
```

And I used `>=` instead of `>` because you didn't specify about equal conditions in plain text. Sample Excel file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofyb2ewd7v7gb76/43108440.xlsx?dl=0). Sample file handles well some ill-formatted input as well.

[image]

Comment: This seems to work.  However, some of my break times are over an hour and the formula is not converting it correctly.  For example in G2, I have one cell listed as 64:10 and the conversion is 0:45

Comment: Well, I don't know why 0:45 is displayed, but 3rd my `if` was wrong anyway. I edited 3rd `if`.

Comment: @sangbok_Lee  Here are my remaining issues.

breaks over an hour are not calculating correctly
If someone works less than an hour, it's not calculating correctly.
Here is a picture showing what it looks like
[link](http://imgur.com/a/ajkiB)

Comment: The image shows staffed time is also ill-formatted! You should've include the image in the question body. Now I ask you again. 1) Does staffed time `8:35:23` mean 8 hours and 35 minutes and 23 seconds? 2) By contrast, does break time `90:04` mean 90 minutes and 4 seconds? 3) `:00:00` means 0 minute and 0 second in both staffed time and break time? 4) Then does staffed time `:51:13` means 51 minutes and 13 seconds, and the same duration for break time is `51:13`?

Comment: I assumed the answers for above my four question is yes and edited the answer more thoroughly bad-format-friendly.

Comment: Thank you for the sample file, the ' in time was messing me up as I did not have it.  Is there a quick way to add the ' to all my times?

Comment: It's never ending... If not all values in column C are formatted to string, you should first format them to string. I updated the sample Excel file. Check it again. If it's not working again, I strongly recommend that you upload your Excel file.

Comment: [testfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1duq1oduvxatofh/test.xlsx?dl=0)
Here is a sample file

Comment: Okay, my last update was very messy. Things get complicated more and more, which is not good for maintaining... Anyway I updated the sample file again. Please check again.

Comment: I put your formulas into my test file and still getting errors when breaks do not have a leading :  Can you update my test file and send back?

Comment: Updated the answer (more proper formula) with new sample file. Please check it again.

Comment: I need to double check everything a bit more but that looks like that did it.  Hard to believe Excel has such a hard time formatting time.  If I format a column as [h]mm.ss, I want the data to be in that format and be able to sum them up.  Should not have to go through these hoops.